# Interbase SQL Multifield Update

Tags: sql, sql-update, interbase

The Database is Interbase (gdb). I have two tables "**RESTS**" and "**FORMS**". Each have several fields but some are identical but may have different values or may have no value at all. The fields that are similar are "**FULLNAME**", "**PRODUCER**" and "**ADDRESS**". And the two tables are linked by "**ALCCODE**".

So what I ask is: *Can an Update have multiple fields so that each field is updated individually?*

Example that I have:

```
Update Rests r 

set r.FULLNAME=(Select f.FULLNAME from FORMS f where (f.FULLNAME is
not null and f.FULLNAME<>'') and f.FULLNAME<>r.FULLNAME and
r.ALCCODE=f.ALCCODE),

r.PRODUCER=(Select f.PRODUCER from FORMS f where (f.PRODUCER is not
null and f.PRODUCER<>'') and f.PRODUCER<>r.PRODUCER and
r.ALCCODE=f.ALCCODE),

r.ADDRESS=(Select f.ADDRESS from FORMS f where (f.ADDRESS is not null
and f.ADDRESS<>'') and f.ADDRESS<>r.ADDRESS and r.ALCCODE=f.ALCCODE)

where ((r.FULLNAME is null or r.FULLNAME='') and Exists(Select
f.FULLNAME from FORMS f where (f.FULLNAME is not null and
f.FULLNAME<>'') and f.FULLNAME<>r.FULLNAME and r.ALCCODE=f.ALCCODE)) 

and ((r.PRODUCER is null or r.PRODUCER='') and Exists(Select
f.PRODUCER from FORMS f where (f.PRODUCER is not null and
f.PRODUCER<>'') and f.PRODUCER<>r.PRODUCER and r.ALCCODE=f.ALCCODE)) 

and ((r.ADDRESSis null or r.ADDRESS='') and Exists(Select f.ADDRESS
from FORMS f where (f.ADDRESS is not null and f.ADDRESS<>'') and
f.ADDRESS<>r.ADDRESS and r.ALCCODE=f.ALCCODE))
```

But it doesn't work the way I want. Actually it doesn't work at all!

Yet, for one field it does:

```
Update Rests r set r.FULLNAME=(Select f.FULLNAME from FORMS f where
(f.FULLNAME is not null and f.FULLNAME<>'') and f.FULLNAME<>r.FULLNAME
and r.ALCCODE=f.ALCCODE) where ((r.FULLNAME is null or r.FULLNAME='')
and Exists(Select f.FULLNAME from FORMS f where (f.FULLNAME is not
null and f.FULLNAME<>'') and f.FULLNAME<>r.FULLNAME and
r.ALCCODE=f.ALCCODE))
```

**How can I make the same for two or more fields in one update?**

Comment: You should attempt to format your code a bit better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In what way?

Comment: Add line breaks. Side-scrolling is very annoying.

Comment: The answer might depend on your database engine, which you didn't specify.

Comment: @DanBracuk Specified!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: "it doesn't work at all" - What does it mean? Reports a syntax error? Throws an error when run? Executes, but doesn't update anything? Executes and results in wrong/inconsistent data...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can improve this code a lot, but as far as it's "not working", I believe your issue is rooted in your `AND` logic. What you have in your question basically says `UPDATE 3 things WHEN condition A AND condition B AND condition C`, meaning this query will not do anything unless ALL THREE parts of your `WHERE` clause are true. If I'm understanding your problem correctly, what your actually intend here is to update each column independently of the rest, so for example if `r.FULLNAME` is missing but `f.FULLNAME` is present, you want to update this field regardless of whether `r.PRODUCER` and `r.ADDRESS` meet the criteria.

In terms of fixing your query, if I've understood your problem correctly, I think the following will do what you want:

```
UPDATE RESTS r
INNER JOIN FORMS f
ON r.ALCCODE = f.ALCCODE
SET r.FULLNAME=coalesce(NULLIF(r.FULLNAME, ''), NULLIF(f.FULLNAME,''))
, r.PRODUCER=coalesce(NULLIF(r.PRODUCER,''), NULLIF(f.PRODUCER,''))
, r.ADDRESS=coalesce(NULLIF(r.ADDRESS,''), NULLIF(f.ADDRESS,''));
```

The first three lines I think are self explanatory, you're joining the two tables based on the common ID. This removes the repeated `r.id = f.id` checks in your query. In terms of the rest:

- `NULLIF(r.FULLNAME, '')` returns `NULL` if `r.FULLNAME = ''`, otherwise it returns the value of `r.FULLNAME`.
- `coalesce(NULLIF(r.ADDRESS,''), NULLIF(f.ADDRESS,''))` - returns the first non-`NULL` value in the list.
- `SET r.FULLNAME=coalesce(NULLIF(r.FULLNAME, ''), NULLIF(f.FULLNAME,''))` will `SET r.FULLNAME =` to the first value which does not equal `NULL` or `''`.

I believe this satisfied all the criteria you were trying to express if your `WHERE` clauses, but do comment if you think I've missed something.

Here is a fiddle of the above doing it's thing: [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/93WhUr6SnxEoGd11gqcxco/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
UPDATE Rests SET 
    FULLNAME= CASE WHEN F.FULLNAME IS null or F.FULLNAME = '' or R.FULLNAME=F.FULLNAME THEN R.FULLNAME ELSE F.FULLNAME END,
    ADDRESS= CASE WHEN F.ADDRESS IS null or F.ADDRESS = '' or R.ADDRESS=F.ADDRESS THEN R.ADDRESS ELSE F.ADDRESS END,
    PRODUCER=CASE WHEN F.PRODUCER IS null or F.PRODUCER = '' or R.PRODUCER=F.PRODUCER THEN R.PRODUCER ELSE F.PRODUCER END
    FROM Rests R,FORMS F
    WHERE R.ALCCODE=F.ALCCODE
```